# The type or namespace name 'IConnectionIdGenerator' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

We are currently using the latest version of SignalR (2.0.0)

What replaced IConnectiondIdGenerator now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an IUserIdProvider:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#selectingclients

You can't replace connection ids.